# Using the du command and piping it using Less

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

How would I perform a `du` command and pipe it using the `less` command?

Is it `du | less`?

Comment: Did that do what you expected?  What's the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `du | less`.
But that will only list directories in the current directory.For example, in my current directory, command `ls` returns like this:

`Make  Test-labelRanges  Test-labelRanges.C`

And `du |less` returns like this:

`8       ./Make
64      .
(END)`

If you want to list all files and directories, use `du * |less`,in which `*` is a wildcard means everything, and the returns should be like this:

`8       Make
36      Test-labelRanges
4       Test-labelRanges.C
(END)`

Another tips: If you need a human-readable format of file size, like 200k, 100M, you need use option `-h`, like this `du -h * |less`, and returns are :

`8.0K    Make
36K     Test-labelRanges
4.0K    Test-labelRanges.C
(END)`